# php memory_usage returns negative value

Tags: php, memory-management

what i suffer to not understand - i have a huge (11M+ rows) db table, where i compare 2 different selects for performance, one of them behaves weird. Each cid has ~1-3 rows, im trying to get count for each.

simplified code goes like :

```
$q1 = 'select cid from cards';
$q2 = 'select cid, count(*) as cnt from cards group by cid';

function test($query){
 $m1 = memory_get_usage();
 $q = DB->query($query);
 $r = $q->fetchAll();
 $m2 = memory_get_usage();
 return [$m2,$m1];
}
```

then i test like this, run few times so i can compare averages

```
print_r( test($q1) );
print_r( test($q2) );
print_r( test($q1) );
print_r( test($q2) );

...
```

On average, every Test w query q2 runs about 7 sec and shows memory used is ~1200MB, which is perfectly ok.

But always a test w query q1 runs, about 25 secs, the memory usage on the end of the loop ($m2 variable) reports a negative value, for example, **-1838646184**. How can this be? How then properly try to measure used memory?

PS: Also tried real usage (`memory_get_usage(1)`) but its almost same result

I tried to measure test script memory usage, and never expected to get a negative value like this

Comment: Are you using PHP 32-bit?

Comment: @WahyuKristianto - very good question, im aware of the 32bit int limit, but afaik, i use 64bit 5.6 on local laragon test machine, because i need it for some archaic system im trying to update. but testing PHP_INT_MAX on this machine tells me value 2147483647

Comment: @WahyuKristianto just tested PHP_INT_SIZE  - it shows me 4 which makes it look i have 32bit, altought phpinfo architecture tells me 64bit...  can it be related ? how can i measure memory usage in this case ?

Comment: Yes.. Let me answer

Comment: maybe it realy could be 32bit limit of int? but can i actually get 5.6 php for windows on real 64bit ??? im using from here: https://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/ file called php-5.6.40-nts-Win32-VC11-x64.zip (nts seems to be for non thread safe)

Comment: php-5.6.40-nts-Win32-VC11-x64.zip indicates that it's a 32-bit version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're getting a negative value for memory usage is that the memory usage exceeds the maximum value for a signed 32-bit integer. When that happens, the integer overflows, and you end up with a negative value. This issue is more likely to occur on a 32-bit PHP installation.

To solve this issue, you can switch to a 64-bit PHP installation, which should correctly report memory usage without overflow issues.

> just tested PHP_INT_SIZE - it shows me 4 which makes it look i have 32bit, altought phpinfo architecture tells me 64bit... can it be related ? how can i measure memory usage in this case ?

You can still be running a 64-bit architecture but have a 32-bit PHP installation. PHP_INT_SIZE returning 4 indicates that you have a 32-bit PHP installation.

In the meantime, you can use the following workaround to get the correct memory usage difference:

```php
function test($query) {
    $m1 = memory_get_usage();
    $q = DB->query($query);
    $r = $q->fetchAll();
    $m2 = memory_get_usage();
    
    // Check for integer overflow and correct it
    if ($m2 < $m1) {
        $m2 += (1 << 32);
    }

    return [$m2, $m1];
}
```

Comment: thanks @wahyu-kristianto that line **(1 << 32)** helped me, great thanks